# Remove from table if value not in array

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

My code is writing from an array "Value1,Value2,Value3" to the table:

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  Value |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Value1 |
+----+--------+
|  2 | Value2 |
+----+--------+
|  3 | Value3 |
+----+--------+
```

I am using a bootstrap Tag field and when I remove Value2, the array changes to "Value1,Value3" but does not delete the Value2 in the database table.

How do I check and remove Value2?

This is my current code:

```
$commaList = explode(', ', $support_membership);

            foreach ($commaList as $value) {
                $sql = "select * from groups where value like '$value' ";
                $rs = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
                if (!$rs) error_dlg(mysqli_error($database));

                if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) == 1){
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    $sqlgroup = "insert into groups set ";
                    $sqlgroup .= "system='2', ";
                    $sqlgroup .= "value='$value' ";
                    mysqli_query($database, $sqlgroup);
                }
```

Comment: `insert into groups set` Are you sure you use proper `INSERT` syntax?

Comment: It works great inserting the values, it is removing a value from the table. I have a feeling I need an elseif somewhere to check if the values in the array is in the table, and remove the ones in the table that is not in the array.

Comment: @Q-sup where are u deleting? the code just select and insert

Comment: @u_mulder https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile - I haven't had a working code yet.

Comment: @Q-sup add the code that u have that is not working yet

Comment: I have no idea what would work to achieve this. `$sql = "delete * from groups where system = '2' ";`